# I need help with the timing of fadeIn() fadeOut() and delay() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

So here is my function:

```
function homepageRotator()
{
    var numofimgs = $('#backgroundimageholder_home img').length;
    var index = 0;
//run the rotator
rotator();

function rotator()
{
    $('#backgroundimageholder_home img').eq(index).fadeIn('1000').delay(3000*3).fadeOut('1000');
    $('#contentcontainer_home ul li').eq(index).fadeIn('1000').delay(3000*3).fadeOut('1000');
    index = index + 1;

    if(index == numofimgs)
    {
        index = 0;
    }

    setTimeout(function() {rotator()},5000)
}
}
```

So, what I've got is a simple rotator, but the rotation timing seems irratic. When it first loads, none of the timings are right, the first image appears, stays for 3 seconds then switches. Then the next one fades in, and goes away fast. Finally the 3rd one stays on for like 6 seconds then shows the first one then dissapears. Basically it's very irratic and I need to understand why.

Thanks for all the help.

OK, sorry I should have provided more information, so here's basic html layout for this:

```
<div class="backgroundimageholder_home" id="backgroundimageholder_home">
    <?php foreach($front->result() as $row) { ?>
    <img src="images/homepage/<?php echo $row->image; ?>" alt="" class="backgroundimage_home" />
    <?php } ?>
</div>

<div class="contentcontainer_home" id="contentcontainer_home">
    <ul>

        <?php foreach($front->result() as $row) { ?>
        <li>
            <div class="contentcontainer_top_home clearafter" id="contentcontainer_top_home">
                <h2><?php echo $row->name; ?></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo $row->text; ?>
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="contentcontainer_bot_home" id="contentcontainer_bot_home">
                <a href="<?php echo $row->link; ?>" title="">CLICK HERE TO VIEW</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>

    </ul>
</div>
```

So basically my rotator rotates the script, and then it also rotates some captions, that describe the image being shown at the time. That's why I need them to rotate at the same time. I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do this, but I couldn't figure it out. What I really wanted to happen in all honesty was that there was a delay between the image and the caption:
 - fade in image
 - 2 seconds delay
 - fade in caption
 - 5 seconds delay
 - fade out caption
 - fade out image
 repeat

But that was blowing my mind. I could barely get them to rotate correctly without somethign overlappting, etc... anyhow, as always, everyone's help is appreciated.

Comment: what browser are you using? do you get erratic timing in all browsers?

Comment: You are querying the same selectors multiple times. Why?

Comment: can you please provide some more information? e.g. the HTML layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is asynchronous. This is especially evident when you start using timeouts. Your call to `setTimeout()` calls `rotator()` every 5 seconds regardless of whether or not the last call to `rotator()` has completed.

Your `rotator()` itself should take 11 seconds to complete (maybe slightly more since it's two calls). You should set the timeout to more than 11 seconds. 12 should be enough to smooth it out and make it consistent. Secondly use `setInterval`. That will help as well. Remove your `setTimeout` call in the `rotator()` function and put this after the initial call to `rotator()` (or remove the initial call and just wait 12 seconds and it will start as well)

```
setInterval(function() {rotator()},12000);
```

**Edit:**

Explaination of setInterval

Comment: I swear I tried that, and it just doesn't seem to work for me. I don't think I was using correctly or in the right place.